# How to pass a value to an activity from another WITHOUT starting it?

Tags: android, android-intent, parameter-passing

I want to pass a value from activity A to activity B without actually starting the activity B (therefore this rules out the use of Intents and putExtra). The activity B may or may not be started but when it does it needs to display the value passed to it by activity A.

I searched high and low but couldn't find any relevant solution to this seemingly simple question. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If B doenn't start then what is need for extra?

Comment: i think you should use Application class for global variables

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, the activity B **may or may not be started**

Comment: You can always create a singleton and cache your data there but I wouldn't suggest this as it can cause memory leaks

Comment: @Garima use application class for that.. its very useful for that..

Comment: @SamirMangroliya, need to push around a large amount of variables from one activity to another, making them all Application classes is not a very good idea I assume?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari so why are you not used Map or List for large variables

Comment: @SamirMangroliya, By large variables I mean larg number of variables in multiple classes. My bad for the vague lingo.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari if you have large number of variables in multiple classes then why are you not put it in app class ? you can easily access from app class.

Comment: @Garima : i have a simple solution to your question.. may these help you.. Just Try to use SQLiteDatabase Class.. i mean use DATABASE to store values.. and Fetch them in any another activity that you want...

Comment: @GarimaTiwari Use Shared Preferences from Activity A save data and get it in Activity B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **global class** like :

```
public class AppConfig {

    Context context;
    public AppConfig(Context mxt) {

        context = mxt;
    }

    public static String filepath = null;
```

Then, in **activity A** before `onCreate()` :

```
AppConfig config;
Context context;
```

and in `onCreate()` method put this :

```
context = getApplicationContext();
config = new AppConfig(context);
```

And, in second **Activity B** before `onCreate()` :

```
AppConfig config;
Context context;
```

And, in `onCreate()` method put this :

```
context = getApplicationContext();
config = new AppConfig(context);
```

And set the value where you want. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can't find a solution, because it's something that goes against any logic. 
Activity B can't do anything if not started and visible. Activity B might even already be destroyed by the system without you knowing.

You can use a lot of things to set some variables, which your Activity B can read such as in your Application, somewhere in your XML or simply any random class.

Still, you can not actually **DO** anything with any of these options, until you **start** Activity B  and when you can, it will just effectively be the same as giving the extra data in the Intent.

Comment: @Garima: This is correct, if only Activity A can start Activity B, I don't see why you don't want the use of Intents.

Comment: Let me put it this way, you start an online transaction and on the first page it asks you for your name, the transaction then proceeds from one page to another asking for other details (the transaction might terminate midway due to some reason) and then at the end of the transaction the last page says **BYE <name>**. Now I want to be able to store the name from the first page and pass it to the last page (in case the control ever reaches there). **Get the picture?**

Comment: Define page! Is each page an Activity?

Comment: You should do this in Fragments instead, take a look at Roman Nurik's wizard UI: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/wizardpager/   ,  https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6cVymZvn3f4

Comment: Also, just as a note, even with you explaining your situation more I still do not see what this has to do with needing a variable in Activities that aren't started yet. It would work 'fine' with starting a new Activity and passing the previous data into a Bundle everytime to the new Activity.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn, I dont see how I can make myself clearer than this.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari Me neither ;) You have no use of variables in Activities that aren't started yet. An Activity that isn't started can not execute any logic. Your situation can simply be archived by saving the user input in any class that is globally reachable or by passing the data with Intents. The correct solution would be using Fragments, which results in only 1 Activity holding these Fragments automatically granting you a 'global' place to save the user input. Good luck.

Comment: @Garima: I would have created a class which implements Parcelable, call this class for instance Person. And then you can add all the attributes to it, like: name, age etc. Then you can send it with intents as Parcelable.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn. haha, alright. thank you for your efforts still :]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Using this one Activity can set Value into it, and other activity can read from it.

Comment: Shared Preferences does not suit my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to keep a value for an activity . If it starts it means you have to use those values, otherwise you will discard those values. For this you can use a separate class with a variable of datatype that you want and you can create getter setter for that and you can use it.

Make use of the classes

```
public class GetSet {

    public GetSet() {
        super();
    }

    private static boolean passwordSet = false;

    public static boolean isPasswordSet() {
        return passwordSet;
    }

    public static void setPasswordSet(boolean passwordSet) {
        GetSet.passwordSet = passwordSet;
    }
}
```

You can access ths  using `GetSet.setPasswordSet(false);`
and `Boolean flag = GetSet.isPasswordSet();`

Answer (score 0):

Set the value as Global:

public class Global {

```
public static int mValue;   


public static int getValue() {
    return mValue;
}

public static void setValue(int mValue) {
    Global.mValue = mValue;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answers to that but I couldn't find it. So I found a way to do that.

First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Flag" , true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity

```
boolean flag;
flag = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Flag" ,false);
    if(flag == true)
    {
        this.finish();
    }
```

So now you may send any data you want it will open the Second Activity and then immediately close it after you wouldn't even realize it. You may use Shared prefences to save your data for after usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is not so bad as people say, sometimes you need to leave some message for some activity.
You do not need any new technology to store data. Use storage depending on your data type: you can use SharedPrefs, DB or just a field in your application class if you do not need it to be persistent, or store it on a server or cloud if you want it to live longer than uninstalls.